# Can i use website domain as author for open source license?

Tags: license-notice, license-file

When in the open source licenses is required to indicate the author, can i use simply the domain of the website (not the company name)?

@curiousdannii thanks for point me this other question, but i don't think that answer to my question.

I'm no talking about just for the MIT license, and my request is for use the websites domain, not a general unregistered company.

Comment: The copyright notice must identify the copyright holder, which is usually a natural person, a legal entity (such as a company), or a set of multiple copyright holders. A domain name is not a legal entity that can hold any rights. The linked question is not specific to the MIT license and answers this perfectly.

Comment: Thanks amon, a pseudonym it's ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, modern copyright law imposes no requirement to include a copyright notice whatsoever. You could include no copyright notice, and your work would be just as covered by copyright law as a work with a copyright notice. So, yes, it's likely fine to use a domain name in any copyright notice that you choose to include, with a few caveats.

1. While your copyright is safely intact regradless, you may be forfeiting some procedural advantage by not using your name or a proper peusdonym. For example, in the U.S., per [17 U.S.C. §401(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/401), a valid copyright notice requires

   > (3) the name of the owner of copyright in the work, or an abbreviation by which the name can be recognized, or a generally known alternative designation of the owner.

   I don't know that a domain name would qualify as an "alternative designation of the owner" (possibly, but I really don't know).

   However, even if it does not qualify, the consequences of the invalidity of your notice are virtually zero. The only advantage (in the U.S.) follows in §401(d):

   > **(d)Evidentiary Weight of Notice.—**
   >   If a notice of copyright in the form and position specified by this section appears on the published copy [...] then no weight shall be given to such a defendant’s interposition of a defense based on innocent infringement [...]

   A valid notice can invalidate an infringer's claim of innocent infringement, and that's really it. You can probably beat a claim of innocent infringement with an almost-valid copyright notice anyway.
2. A more serious issue is that domain names are often trademarks. Whether registered or not, they signify the source of goods and services. If you *don't* own the domain you're using (e.g., if I did `Copyright 2018 www.google.com` but I don't work for Google) then that could easily be trademark infringement for misrepresenting the source of your code. Of course, you wouldn't tell a baldfaced lie like saying your code came from google.com, *but* that issue still might arise if you ever abandon the domain. If you forfeit the registration for your chosen domain and someone else buys it to run a completely different site, your code could be legally problematic for claiming association with some `foo.com` when you no longer own `foo.com`.